# Inject dependency from background tasks

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I am new to spring and I am trying to figure out how to Autowire an object to a controller.  The object is created at runtime from a task that is started and stopped using a ServletContextListener.  How do I tell the spring application context about this object?

**More Details**

My background task is started with the code below.  I'd like the `alertServer` object wired to a controler.  Can I modify this class to do that?

```
@WebListener
public class ExecutorContextListener implements ServletContextListener
{
   private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ExecutorContextListener.class);

   Thread backgroundThread;
   AlertServer alertServer;

   @Override
   public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event)
   {
      // Start the AlertServer
      alertServer = new AlertServer();

      backgroundThread = new Thread(alertServer, "AlertServer");
      backgroundThread.start();

   }

   @Override
   public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event)
   {
      alertServer.stop();
      try
      {
         backgroundThread.join();
      }
      catch (InterruptedException e)
      {
         log.error("contextDestroyed Exception", e);
      }
   }
}
```

**UPDATE**

The comments and answers provided were very helpful in finding a solution.  With the info provided by Sotirios Delimanolis, and Dave Newton I realized that now that I'm building my solution on top of Spring, I don't really need to use a ServletContextListener in the first place.  All I really wanted to do was start a background thread that is available to Spring controllers, so I put this code in my servlet-context.xml and I am up and running.

```
<beans:bean id="alertServer" class="com.springmvcproj.AlertServer">
    <beans:property name="serverPort" value="56543" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="AlertServerThread" class="java.lang.Thread" init-method="start">
  <beans:constructor-arg ref="alertServer"/>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: Spring wires using Spring-managed objects. How are you creating the object?

Comment: Everything I've done in my background task is done with POJOs. Do I need to add annotations to some of those classes?

Comment: You'd be better off injecting an alert server into a Spring application startup listener, and into your controllers, assuming there's only the one.

Answer (score 1):

As Dave Newton has stated in the comments, Spring can only inject beans it manages into other beans it manages. A class annotated with `@WebListener` is a class managed by the servlet container and so never appears in your Spring context. Even if it does (because you create a `bean` entry), it won't be the same one the servlet container uses.

A way around this is to use Spring's `WebApplicationInitializer` instead (or alongside) of using a `web.xml` descriptor. This interface provides an `onStartup(ServletContext)` method where you can register Servlets, Filters, and Listeners just like you would in a `web.xml` or with `@WebXXX`. Something like

```
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
// Create the 'root' Spring application context
    final AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.register(YourApplicationContext.class); // or some xml file
    rootContext.refresh();

    // Manage the life-cycle of the root application context
    container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

    // Create the dispatcher servlet's context
    final AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    dispatcherContext.register(DispatcherContext.class);

    final ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
    dispatcher.setAsyncSupported(true);
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");

    container.addListener(dispatcherContext.getBean(ExecutorContextListener.class)));

    ...// more registrations
}
```

Therefore the above assumes that your `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext` contains a bean of type `ExecutorContextListener`. Because Spring is managing this bean, you can have added `@Autowired` or `@Inject` to inject the same `AlertServer` instance in both this `ServletContextListener` and a `@Controller` class. In this scenario you wouldn't initialize it in the `contextInitialized()` method.

A second alternative is to

1. Add the `AlertServer` object as an attribute in the `ServletContext`.
2. Inject the `ServletContext` into your `@Controller` class.
3. Retrieve the `AlertServer` object from the `ServletContext` attributes.

The above is possible because the `contextInitialized()` method is always run before any of your controllers start handling requests.